Why is my .remove command not working when my .append command is working fine
I'm working on the classroom project where you make a little text based game as an introduction to Python. My dictionary, and most of the if/else for moving between rooms is working fine. Where I'm running into trouble is in the item/inventory sequence.
I have a dictionary that shows the connections between rooms , and what item is in each room, and then I have 2 lists. The first list contains all of the items, and the second is the player inventory.
The idea is that the player inputs the command to get an item. the code then confirms that the item is in the current room in the dictionary AND in the item_list(which is the reference list). Once that happens, the item is added to the players inventory list.
At that point, the item is SUPPOSED to be removed from the reference list so the code no longer shows it as an option to pick up. However, the .remove line of code I'm using isn't working, despite being the exact same setup as the .append code for the inventory list, which is working perfectly.
The code sequence is as follows:
'rooms' is teh dictionary, item_list is the refence list, and inventory is where the items go when the player gets the item
rooms = { #defines the locations, the relationships between the locations, and locates the items not yet in inventory
        'Great Hall':
                {'South': 'South Hall', 'North': 'North Hall', 'West': 'Entrance', 'East': 'Kitchen'},
        'South Hall':
                {'North': 'Great Hall', 'East': 'Dungeon', 'item': 'a Mirror'},
        'Dungeon':
                {'West': 'South Hall', 'item': 'a Shield'},
        'North Hall':
                {'South': 'Great Hall', 'East': 'Tower', 'item': 'a Hand Mirror'},
        'Tower':
                {'West': 'North Hall', 'item': "Odin's Staff"},
        'Kitchen':
                {'West': 'Great Hall', 'North': 'Dining Room', 'item': 'a bowl of Nuts'},
        'Entrance':
                {'East': 'Great Hall', 'item': 'a Torch'},
        'Dining Room':
                {'South': 'Kitchen'}}
directions = ['North', 'South', 'East', 'West'] #defines player movement options
item_list = ['a Mirror', 'a Shield', 'a Hand Mirror', "Odin's Staff", 'a bowl of Nuts', 'a Torch'] #reference for the 'Get item' command
inventory = [] #list to be populated with items as they are collected by the player
current_room = 'Entrance' #starting point, updates to output current location when player moves
def player_status():
        print('You are in the', current_room)  # status
        print('Inventory:', inventory)
        print('You see:', rooms.get(current_room).get('item'))
while True:
        if current_room == 'Dining Room': #win condition
                if len(inventory) == 6:
                        print('Win condition text')
                else: #lose condition
                        print('Lose condition text')
                break

        player_status()
        command = input('What would you like to do?')
        if command in directions: #moves player in the direction indicated by input.
                if command in rooms.get(current_room).keys():
                        current_room = rooms[current_room].get(command)
                else: #shows if input is not in dictionary
                        print('There is nothing in that direction.')
        elif command == 'Get item': #The command for adding an item to inventory.
                if rooms.get(current_room).get('item') in item_list:
                        inventory.append(rooms.get(current_room).get('item'))
                        item_list.remove(rooms.get(current_room).get('item'))
                        print('You acquired:',rooms.get(current_room).get('item'))
                else:
                    print("There's nothing here.")
        else:
                print("I'm sorry, I don't understand that command")

The inventory.append line works perfectly, but for whatever reason the item_list.remove is doing nothing.
Help?
edit: added the full code for readability

you must provide a [mcve]

This seems like it should work; did you put a print(item_list) right after the item_list.remove() call to confirm that the remove didn't do anything?

@AidenChow I just added the rest of the code. the code shows the updated room status after the command is input, and it's still showing that the item is there, which in theory means the item is still satisfying the  "if rooms.get(current_room).get('item') in item_list:" command
ETA: Sonofabitch, you're right. that .remove command IS working, it's the current room command that's fucky

@juanpa.arrivillaga added the rest of the code for readability

.remove raises a ValueError if the item to remove didn't exists in the list. Since you're not getting an error, the .remove is working. Removing the item_list variable and instead moving things directly between the containers (rooms, player inventory, etc.) would help a lot in avoiding the kind of issue you're having. (The specific issue you ask about is because you don't do any checks when printing the room content. Had you moved the room item directly into the player inventory, the issue you asked about would not have occurred.)

I've done a small snippet of code as an example in case it would help
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "mango", "raspberry"]
fruits_ref = fruits
fruits_ref.remove("apple")
    
print(fruits)       #['banana', 'mango', 'raspberry']
print(fruits_ref)   #['banana', 'mango', 'raspberry']

also from experience I suggest making rooms.get(current_room).get('item') a variable of its own (read about DRY principle)

ok, the .remove command is working fine, turns out the issue is in the current_room command.
BACK TO THE DRAWING BOARD

Just close the question if it was inappropriate.
